# How to move figures to an extra page?

Tags: floats

I have two large figures that I'd like to put on an extra page, meaning there should be no text on that page, only the figures.

```
Bla bla.

\begin{figure}[t] ... \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b] ... \end{figure}

Lorem ipsum.
```

I'd like that to come out as:

```
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
  Lorem ipsum bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  bla  bla
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

-- pagebreak

Figure 1 (at the top)
Figure 2 (at the bottom)

-- pagebreak

bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
```

I haven't found anything on Google - inserting pagebreaks manually may work but won't make the text continue (the "Lorem Ipsum" part would be *after* the figures, even when there is some space left on the page before).

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `[p]` not `[t]`

to force the figure on to a float page.

Comment: Ouch, no idea how I've missed that. Thanks a lot!